# ts files, available in final implementation (app engine) - google cloud

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-app-engine

I'm implementing a project made in react, along with an api in node. after carrying out all the necessary steps to complete the implementation, I tested the application and saw that in the browser, all my ts files are available. this behavior is normal, and the first time I do the implementation by google

[result when viewing the source files of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJnMK.png)

I don't know if this behavior is normal, but in my opinion, as the .tsx/.ts files are not interpreted by the browser, they should not be available to the user

at first I thought I had problems sending the files (I forgot to ignore something), so I tried to rewrite the ".gcloudignore" file, adding any file that had no relation to the final implementation of the project

[image of skipped files/folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwzQe.png)

Thank you in advance for the attention of everyone who stopped to read this request for help. grateful

Comment: What you're asking isn't clear. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I needed help to understand if it is correct for ts/tsx type files to be available when a client makes a request on my website (source code exposed), according to my company's management, this is a bad practice. will give me the order to solve this problem.

Comment: I suspect I'm doing something wrong when sending my files to the app engine (google cloud)

Comment: You're saying that you deployed your App to GAE, and when a user navigates to your site (e.g. your home page), and right-click and select view source, what they see is your directory structure?

Comment: this, in addition to seeing the build files used in production (.js), it also sees the development files (ts)

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem. I thought I had configured the ".gcloudignore" file the wrong way (not ignoring the development files), but I saw that everything was ok

Comment: then I tried to delete the development folders before sending the code to GAE, to see if it would solve it, but I was unsuccessful

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, so I decided to migrate the project to nextJs. with the use of this framework, my problem was solved.
when the production files are created, only these are sent to GAE, thus solving my source file exposure problem

Comment: okay. I think I saw someone else with a similar problem. Would be interesting to know the root cause